# Extracting raw data from SQLite file

Tags: perl, sqlite, hex

As you may or may not know, when data is deleted from an SQLite file, it still remains within the file. It can be viewed using a hex editor, but will not show up in SQLite or any SQLite viewer.

How can I extract this data so that it is still legible? I'm thinking some kind of perl script but if SQLite can't see the data and I can only see it in a hex editor, I'm not sure what to do.

Any ideas?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If sqlite can't see the rows then you'll need to parse the raw file-format yourself. That's not going to be easy.

There's a commercial tool that can do it [epilog](http://www.ccl-forensics.com/Software/epilog-from-ccl-forensics.html) - don't know how good it is or how well it works. Might be worth it for you.

Failing that, you'll need to parse the file format yourself. Some hints are [here](http://antiforensics.net/Computer-Forensics/an-analysis-of-the-record-structure-within-sqlite-databases.html) or you might want to hack the sqlite code itself and see if you can get it to ignore whatever deleted markers there are.

Oh - if you vacuum the db file it will actually remove the deleted rows, so don't.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the **[HexDump](http://search.cpan.org/~ftassin/Data-HexDump-0.02/lib/Data/HexDump.pm)** package for Perl

The following code will print the hex to the screen, where *FooFile* is the path to your sqllite file:

```
use Data::HexDump;

my $f = new Data::HexDump;
$f->file("FooFile");
$f->block_size(1024);
print while $_ = $f->dump;
```